# Finding the smallest number of nodes that must be added to make a binary tree balanced?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, binary-search-tree

Suppose that you are given an arbitrary binary tree.  We'll call the tree *balanced* if the following is true for all nodes:

1. That node is a leaf, or
2. The height of the left subtree and the height of the right subtree differ by at most ±1 and the left and right subtrees are themselves balanced.

Is there an efficient algorithm for determining the minimum number of nodes that need to be added to the tree in order to make it balanced?  For simplicity, we'll assume that nodes can only be inserted as leaf nodes (like the way that a node is inserted into a binary search tree that does no rebalancing).

Comment: why would you need to add nodes. wouldn't you just rebalance it without adding new ones?

Comment: @nathanhayfield- If I was trying to build a balanced binary search tree, then yes, it would be best to try to rebalance the tree.  This is more of a hypothetical question.

Comment: Calculate the height at every node, done?

Comment: @AlexDiCarlo- If there is a height difference of +6 at a node, can you use that to immediately infer how many nodes must be added to the smaller tree to get the balance factor to correct to +1?

Comment: If the height difference is +6, then you would just add 5 nodes to the shorter tree... No? (I.e. in a linked-list type fashion)

Comment: To further clarify, find the furthest leaf in the shorter tree, insert a leaf node there, then another on that leaf node, and so on.

Comment: @nathanhayfield What is zero? We're talking about re-balancing by inserting new nodes, not re-balancing by moving nodes around.

Comment: What would be the point of this new tree (where potentially half the nodes are garbage just to make the balanced property hold)?

Comment: @AlexDiCarlo- My apologies - I had the wrong definition down.  The left and right subtrees must be recursively themselves balanced, meaning that making a linked list on the left and right sides wouldn't actually make the tree balanced.

Comment: Maybe this question would do better on [cs.stackexchange.com](http://cs.stackexchange.com), [cstheory](http://cstheory.stackexchange.com), or [programmers](http://programmers.stackexchange.com)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following tree fits into your definition, although it doesn't seem very balanced to me:

[image: Depth 5 "balanced" tree]

**EDIT** This answer is wrong, but it has enough interesting stuff in it that I don't feel like deleting it yet. The algorithm produces a balanced tree, but not a minimal one. The number of nodes it adds is:

[image]

where `n` ranges over all nodes in the tree, `lower(n)` is the depth of the child of `n` with the lower depth and `upper(n)` is the depth of the child of `n` with the higher depth. Using the fact that the sum of the first `k` fibonacci numbers is `fib(k+2)-1`, we can replace the inner sum with `fib(upper(n)) - fib(lower(n) + 2)`.

The formula is (more or less) derived from the following algorithm to add nodes to the tree, making it balanced (in python, only showing the relevant algorithms):

```
def balance(tree, label):
  if tree is None:
    return (None, 0)
  left, left_height = balance(tree.left_child, label)
  right, right_height = balance(tree.right_child, label)
  while left_height < right_height - 1:
    left = Node(label(), left, balanced_tree(left_height - 1, label))
    left_height += 1
  while right_height < left_height - 1:
    right = Node(label(), right, balanced_tree(right_height - 1, label))
    right_height += 1
  return (Node(tree.label, left, right), max(left_height, right_height) + 1)

def balanced_tree(depth, label):
  if depth <= 0:
    return None
  else:
    return Node(label(),
                balanced_tree(depth - 1, label),
                balanced_tree(depth - 2, label))
```

As requested: report the count instead of creating the tree:

```
def balance(tree):
  if tree is None:
    return (0, 0)
  left, left_height = balance(tree.left_child)
  right, right_height = balance(tree.right_child)
  while left_height < right_height - 1:
    left += balanced_tree(left_height - 1) + 1
    left_height += 1
  while right_height < left_height - 1:
    right += balanced_tree(right_height - 1) + 1
    right_height += 1
  return (left + right, max(left_height, right_height) + 1)

def balanced_tree(depth):
  if depth <= 0:
    return 0
  else:
    return (1 + balanced_tree(depth - 1)
              + balanced_tree(depth - 2))
```

*Edit*: Actually, I think that other than computing the size of a minimum balanced tree of depth n more efficiently (i.e. memoizing it, or used the closed form: it's just `fibonacci(n+1)-1`), that's probably as efficient as you can get, since you have to examine every node in the tree in order to test the balance condition, and that algorithm looks at every node precisely once.

Comment: @rici- Yep, that tree is balanced.  However, I think that your code will produce the smallest balanced tree, rather than reporting the number of nodes needed to get up to balance.

Comment: @templatetypedef: yup, that's what it does. There's probably a more efficient way of figuring out the number of nodes than just counting them, although I'm too tired to figure it out. It should be trivial to see how to modify the code to report the count rather than construct the tree.

Comment: @templatetypedef: obviously it would be better to cache the values of balanced_tree (which is, in any case, fibonacci(i)-1), but there you go.

Comment: @templatetypedef: actually, it doesn't produce the smallest balanced tree; although it does produce a balanced tree. I realized today that producing the smallest balanced tree is a lot harder, particularly since it may require fewer additions to increase by two the depth of a depth n-1 balanced tree than to increase by one the depth of a depth n balanced tree. So I now think it will take at least two passes, or perhaps some kind of bottom-up DP algorithm.

Answer (score 1):

Will this work?

Go recursively from the top. If the node A is imbalanced, add a node B on the short side and and enough left nodes to node B until node A is balanced.

(Of course, count the nodes added.)

Comment: @xpda- My apologies - I had the wrong definition of balance.  The left and right subtrees must also themselves be balanced, not just have the same height as one another.  AS a result, I don't think this will work any more.

Comment: Are you sure? They should be balanced as you progress downward through the tree recursively.

Answer (score 1):

First let's find the height of left child and right child of each node.

Now consider the root of the tree it's height is

> `1+max(height(root.left) , height(root.right))`.

let's assume left has height of n-1 then right should have minimum height of n-2. Let's define another relation here *req[node] -> the minimum required height of each node to make the tree balanced*.

if you observe for a node to be at height `h` one of it's children should be at least at n-1 and to make it balanced the other children should be at at least n-2.

start from root with *req[root] = height of root*

The pseudo code is :

```
    def chk_nodes(root, req):

      if(root == NULL):
        return minNodes(req)

      if(left[root] > right[root]):
       return chk_nodes(root.left  , req-1) + chk_nodes(root.right , req-2)

      else return chk_nodes(root.left , req-2) + chk_nodes(root.right , req-1)
```

Now what is minNodes(int req)?

It's a function which return *'minimum no of nodes required to create a balanced binary tree of height h'*. the function is quite intuitive and self-explanatory.

```
      def minNodes(int req) :
          if req < 0 : return 0
          return 1 + minNodes(req-1) + minNodes(req-2)
```

In minNodes function , a lookup table can be used to make it O(1) lookup time and O(N) for construction.

when the chk_nodes function runs recursively , at leaf-nodes we will be left with left-node , req . if that req > 0  then there should be a new sub-tree (balanced) with height req. Hence minNodes( req ) are required at this particular leaf-node.

With only 2 traversals and `O(N)` time, `O(N)` space the problem is solved.